# Custom navigation button resizing problems when changing orientation (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, autoresizingmask

I am creating a custom navigation button (as below) and all is going well except for one thing...

```
UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
btn.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,40,40);
btn.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
UIBarButtonItem* barBtn = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barBtn;
```

...if I start off in portrait then push another view controller onto the navigation then change orientation to landscape then pop the top view controller, the custom navigation button doesn't auto adjust its size (and so is too large for the navbar.)

It resizes ok when the button is visible.

If I substitute a UISegmentedControl for the UIButton then that also works (even when the orientation is changed and another viewcontroller is ontop.)

Anyone know what the magic flag is that I've not set?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 btn.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but that's not the solution. It auto sizes just fine when rotated - so long as it belongs to the topmost viewcontroller - which makes me think that it's more of a navigation/viewcontroller thing.